# Get name from marker on the current location in google app in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have already created an android map app to load nearest restaurant based on users current location. And already have a rating bar activity to enter rating, store and retrieve in database. Now what I need is how to link this rating bar for that particular restaurant. Is there any way to get the name of the restaurant alone from marker and store then in rating bar database.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on how you are implementing and which version of API is being used.

From [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#getTitle()), we see a method is available to get the title of the marker. Simple use the getTitle() method available.

From docs:

> **public String getTitle ()**
>
> Gets the title of the marker.
>
> Returns A string containing the marker's title.

So on a **Marker** object, you can do the following:

```
String title = marker.getTitle();
String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setonmarkerClickListener.. when user click on marker.. it will trigger your rating bar

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker1) {
                String name = marker1.getTitle();
                String id = marker1.getId();
                LatLng location = marker1.getPosition();

                //create a custom dialog which contain ratingbar
                //send the result to server
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

// get address by Geocoder

```
 Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                if (addresses.isEmpty()) {
                    //yourtextfieldname.setText("Waiting for Location");
                    markerOptions.title("Waiting for Location");
                   // markerOptions.title("Current Position");
                }
                else {
                    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                        Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);
                        String localityString = returnAddress.getLocality();
                        String city = returnAddress.getCountryName();
                        String region_code = returnAddress.getCountryCode();
                        String zipcode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();
                        StringBuilder  str = new StringBuilder();
                        str.append(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1)+" "+addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2) + " ");
                        str.append(localityString + " ");
                        str.append(city + " ");
                        str.append(region_code + " ");
                        str.append(zipcode + " ");
    //                    yourtextfieldname.setText(addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getLocality() +", " + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
                        markerOptions.title(str.toString());
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Address:- " + addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + addresses.get(0).getLocality(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
```